# ADO.NET Known Issues?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, architecture, ado.net

So, I'm starting a new Project in my company, and it's kinda big. We are going to use .NET 3.5, and I wish to known if there are any know bugs or perfomance issues that could give weird behaviour for my project? I'm reading some things about EFv4 and all they say is that EFv3.5 have too many problems.

After all, what's the best and fastest way, ADO.NET Entities or extract the data from my DB directly to a DataReader? The EF Oracle provider is stable?

The project will be .NET 3.5 and Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you'll experience out of the gate will be the Oracle/EF hurdle.  Since neither Oracle or MS provide one you'll have to go third party.  [There are a few out there](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=oracle+entity+framework+provider).

There are other ORM's out there.. maybe this is a good comparison?
http://ormeter.net/

I also think your question might be better served by asking "What ORM should I use given X technology".  You should be picking an ORM based on your requirements and constraints.

Comment: ormeter does not seem to deal with Oracle.

Comment: My advice would be to cross reference a list of oracle EF provider with ormeter to pick the best provider based on your needs.  Or as I suggested, re-evaluate EF with other ORM's.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you were looking to EF you might also consider Nhibernate which in my expirience is much better. At work we tried both and chose the second because you can also write some  raw Sql (hql) query in it.

If you still decide to use Ado I and the size of the project is big you'll need an amount of discipline not to mess with sql query strings around.

PS:
Forgot to mention that NHibernate supports also linq which also generates better and cleaner sql queries comparing to EF.